# Can a big box store sue me or demand I return items I did not order?

Tags: california, consumer-protection, online

I'm in California for reference.

I've been working with the kitchen design people at a big box store and they came out and did the measurements. They were paid for by me. We decided on a design after a month or two of delays and after I got a bid I waited on it.

Then I received a “thank you for your order” from said big box store for cabinets. I forwarded the email to the design lady and she said it's an error.

Fast forward, I was called and told by a delivery company that they needed to deliver my cabinets.

They delivered the cabinets and they were unpaid. The invoice shows paid.

They called me, delivered, and I signed.

I did not make this order, I do not have the power to make such order. This was an error by their associate. The order was sent to the manufacturer, who I imagine was paid by the big box store.

Today, a week post delivery- I received an email that states the delivery was an error and they need to send out someone to pick up the cabinets.

My question is not a moral one. My question is, what are my legal rights here?

Does my signing screw me?

Is someone going to show up and harass me?

Will I be sued?

Is over a certain amount of money matter?

I did not ask for this. I did not okay an order.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You signed for the delivery, so it sort of sounds like you did, in fact, OK the order.

Comment: I okayed the delivery, I did not sign at time of order to be clear. 

I did not okay the ordering ANY items. Not sure if this matters?

Comment: I don't think it does. I guess I'm not clear on why there's a problem, though. If you don't want them and they're offering to pick them up, it seems like everything should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

#### Errors are not a windfall

You didn't pay for the cabinets, you don't get to keep them.  An honest mistake by a company does not give you the right to keep product.

Comment: That is not always true (though it is in this case). Unsolicited merchandise sent through the USPS does not need to be returned.